# Update a progress bar from a C function

Tags: c, swift, pointers, grand-central-dispatch, core-audio

I am working on an audio app for iOS 8 in Swift.
A MIDI file is loaded and, when the user pushes the "Save" button, it is rendered to a file in a C function that manually pulls the samples.
Now, I would like to update a progress bar in the interface for this save action.
I added a property observer to a var in ViewController, and I passed a pointer to this var to the C function, hoping that it would update it during the loop… well, no.
Even if the C function updates the value of the var inside the loop, this update is "fired" only once, at the end.
Is there a way to update the progress bar?
Here is some code.
Thanks!

In ViewController:

```
var outProgressBarValue:Float = 0.0 {
    willSet {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            println("New value received! -> \(newValue)")
            self.progressBarOutlet.setProgress(newValue, animated: true)
        })
    }
}

@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    [...]
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
        WriteOutputFile(url, self.musicSequence!, Sound.sharedInstance.musicPlayer, self.processingGraph,  &self.outProgressBarValue)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            restoreOnlineRendering(processingGraph: self.processingGraph, mainMixerNode: self.mainMixerNode, ioNode: &(self.ioNode))
            self.saveButtonOutlet.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    [...]
}
```

In a linked C file:

```
void WriteOutputFile(CFURLRef url, MusicSequence musicSequence, MusicPlayer musicPlayer, AUGraph processingGraph, float *outProgressBarValue) {  
[…] 
    CheckError(MusicPlayerStart(musicPlayer), "MusicPlayerStart");
    do {
        CheckError(AudioUnitRender (outputUnit, &actionFlags, &tStamp, 0, numFrames, bufferList), "AudioUnitRender");
        tStamp.mSampleTime += (Float64)numFrames;
        CheckError(ExtAudioFileWrite(outfile, numFrames, bufferList), "ExtAudioFileWrite");
        CheckError(MusicPlayerGetTime (musicPlayer, &currentTime), "MusicPlayerGetTime");
        *outProgressBarValue = currentTime / sequenceLength;
        printf("outProgressBarValue:\t %f\n", *outProgressBarValue);
    } while (currentTime < sequenceLength);

    CheckError(MusicPlayerStop(musicPlayer), "MusicPlayerStop"); 
[…] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If observing does not work, why not send the update explicitly to the controller? For example, via NSNotification.

Here is what I did as a proof of concept:

1. Add an Objective-C class file with .h and .m files. No need to define a class in this file, just put your c function in .m, and the declaration in .h.
2. Configure the bridging header, where you import the .h file. The bridging header is typically called "-Bridging-Header.h".
3. You can now just call your function in any swift class.
4. In the .m file with the c function, import "`<UIKit/UIkit.h>`" (or Foundation).
5. When needed, post a notification from your c function similar to this:

   ```
   NSNotification *notif = [[NSNotification alloc] initWithName:@"Update"
      object:nil userInfo:@{@"progress" : @0.42}];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notif];
   ```
6. In the swift file, follow the usual procedure to add `self` as observer for the notification and call the update function with the values passed in the `userInfo` dictionary.

Comment: I tried passing &self.progressBarOutlet.progress to the C function, but this does not work. The problem seems not catching the data in the ViewController, but sending them from the C function. Moreover, without the observer, the controller would not get updated in the main thread, causing a 10 seconds delay in the interface.

Comment: Just put your c function into the controller or another Objective-C class. Always update the UI on the main thread.

Comment: What do you mean? The C function is already called by the ViewController.

Comment: I don't mean the call, I mean the c function itself, put it into the view controller's class. Pass it the controller with something like `myCFunction((__bridge void*)(self));` so it can tell the controller to update the UI. Another way is to declare the variable you need outside the class to make it global.

Comment: I didn't know that you could write a C function inside a ViewController... how can you do it? Could you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of Objective-C. That is of course not possible. Still - could you not pass the controller to the function? Or, better even, could you let the function send NSNotifications?

Comment: Oh, ok. You mean passing the whole ViewController to the C function? I am passing the address of one ot its ivars, for now. Would it change anything? And how will I access a _class_ from plain C, then? NSNotifications seem promising, but how can I invoke them from plain C?

Comment: You could put the plain C function into a UIKit aware class.

Comment: Please see my edit. I was interested how this actually works. I would appreciate an extra up-vote for the effort.